# Is is appropriate to mix inequalities and equalities in a mathematical statement?

Tags: notation, number-comparison

This question is extremely basic but I can't find any information online and it has never been mentioned at university:  Is the use of equal signs within comparisons allowed/mathematically correct?

*Example A:* $$3^2+1^2=10 < 16=(3+1)^2.$$

*Example B:* $$\DeclareMathOperator{fib}{fib}\fib(2)=1 < \fib(3)=2 < \fib(4)=3,$$
where $\fib(n)$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: I think it's fine; it's a short-cut for $3^2+1^2=10$ and $10<16$ and $16=(3+1)^2$

Comment: It's of standard usage.

Comment: okay, thank you everyone. The notation was specifically marked as a mistake on one of my worksheets and I was starting to get really confused, as I thought it was common practise. I will talk to my lecturer about it then...